# How to reset `canOpenURL` limit in iOS9?

Tags: ios, iphone

I built the app with iOS8 SDK and installed it to iOS9 device.
The app calls "canOpenURL" on many distinct URL schemes and the app reached the limit.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:

> If your app is linked against an earlier version of iOS but is running in iOS 9.0 or later, you can call this method on 50 distinct URL schemes. After hitting this limit, subsequent calls to this method return NO. If a user reinstalls or upgrades the app, iOS resets the limit.

Then, I modify the app so that the number of schemes is lower than 50 and update the app.

But the limit has been not yet reset. The *first* call of "canOpenURL" falls into the error:  "This app has exceeded the number of allowed scheme queries"

When I changed Bundle ID, a call of "canOpenURL" was succeeded. But with original Bundle ID, failed.

I tried the followings too, but have the same result:

- reinstall the app
- reboot the device
- delete the app, reboot the device, set date forward a day, reboot the device, and reinstall the app.

How can I reset the limit of canOpenURL?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around it because with your behavior you have tried to trick iOS. Apple does not like this.

Comment: Why don't you include the URLs in your info.plist. You can still target iOS 8 but you won't be relying on the backward compatibility on iOS 9

Comment: @Paulw11 One of the using libraries does not support iOS9 SDK yet and iOS8 SDK ignores LSApplicationQueriesSchemes...

Comment: As long as you compile with Xcode 7.x and include the info.plist entries you can still target iOS 8 and get the correct behaviour on each platform. You may still have a problem with Apple approval if you include many urlschemes for no good reason.

Comment: @Paulw11 I want to use iOS8 SDK and LSApplicationQueriesSchemes are ignored if I use _iOS8_ SDK with Xcode 7.x.

Comment: Would please tell me where to find the original doc referring to this limit declaration? I just don't see it as I followed your link. So I'm wondering whether this limit exists now on.