# How can I check programmatically that list of applications are installed or not in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I'm showing list of applications.Is it possible to find that the array of applications are installed or not in iPhone.
If any possibility is there anyone please provide related code in swift to check the array of applications is installed or not in iPhone.

Comment: Thats an easy answer... you cant do it. Apple do not give you access to a list of installed apps.

Comment: I told you that you cannot do it. apple do not allow it and your response is to ask how to do it?

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I saw it as you can so thats why I asked you again

Answer (score 2):

In the old times you could have used `canOpenURL` with a library like [iHasApp](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp). This only works for apps that register custom deep link schemes, but it was capturing the majority of important apps.

But since iOS 9 there seems to be a limitation to this approach - see [How to reset `canOpenURL` limit in iOS9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564459/how-to-reset-canopenurl-limit-in-ios9)

In general your app is not allowed to know what else is installed in the system for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**From your sandboxed application**

By default from an `Application Layer`, you are not allowed to use the private API's to check what other applications are installed on your device.

Workarounds

1. If the target third-party app supports URL schemes. You can check the url scheme they implement using `[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someScheme://randomText"]]` .
2. (Not recommended)Take a look at private frameworks like  `/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices LSApplicationWorkspace` . There is a method called `allInstalledApplications` in `LSApplicationWorkspace` which should work, check runtime headers for more info.

**Off topic ~ For MDM devices**

Using Mobile Device Management (MDM) protocol, you can use InstalledApplicationList command to get the array of installed applications on the target device. The following is the response for the said MDM command.
[image]

Comment: it seems that using Mobile Device Management (MDM) protocol is the only logical and legal way to get the array of installed applications on the target device.
So my question is how to do the above exactly?